# What tools are available for creating in process COM servers in Java?

Tags: java, com

What tools are available for creating in process COM servers in Java?

Answer (score 1):

[J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/) is the most comprehensive, complete solution you will probably find for using COM and Java together. The software has been used by many commercial products, big and small, to integrate COM and Java (both directions).

Answer (score 1):

jacob-*-x86.dll and accompanied jacob.jar

[Used it](http://td2jira.sourceforge.net) successfully to connect to TestDirector (which uses DCOM). Little bit tricky with memory management, but even .NET guys calling COM have troubles doing it.
link text

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [JNI Wrapper/ComfyJ](http://www.teamdev.com/comfyj/index.jsf) - it allows you to either generate Java proxy classes or use IDispatch. You can also trap and broadcast events (IConnectionPoint) and implement COM servers.

Answer (score 0):

Any software used to access COM from Java (or another platform) is known as a "COM bridge".

The j-Interop project on sourceforge may be worth checking out.